# how to change high resolution image to low resolution using laravel image?

Tags: image, laravel, resolution

I want to implement lazy load of image in my application which needs two pictures i.e one for initial loading which resolution should be smaller and another one should be original picture.

I just want to know is there any function in laravel image which can change the high resolution image to low resolution image just like resizing the picture.

Comment: There's [BKWLD/croppa](https://github.com/BKWLD/croppa)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/use/uploads).

```
Image::make(Input::file('photo'))->resize(300, 200)->save('foo.jpg');
```

Answer (score 3):

for Laravel there is an excellent package [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel)
With its help it is easy to resize, and many other function

Resize example:

```
Image::make('images/originalimage.jpg')->resize(650, null, function ($constraint) {
   $constraint->aspectRatio(); //to preserve the aspect ratio
   $constraint->upsize();
})->save('images/smallimage.jpg');
```